# How do I activate only one bootstrap 4 datepicker with calendar click?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datepicker

I have two Bootstrap 4 Datepicker dates on my page, like this:

```
    <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
        <div>&nbsp;Start Date</div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm date">
                <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="sdate" value="">
                <div class="input-group-append"><span class="input-group-text btn datebtn"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
        <div>&nbsp;End Date</div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm date">
                <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="edate" value="">
                <div class="input-group-append"><span class="input-group-text btn datebtn"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to activate the datepicker with a calendar click. This works, but activates both calendar popups.

```
    $('.datebtn').click(function() {
        $('.datepicker').focus();
    });
```

When I try to find only the closest, traveling up the DOM, nothing happens on click.

```
    $('.datebtn').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.datepicker').focus();
    });
```

I could hard code this with unique IDs for my two inputs, and that works, but I want this to be generic for the entire application, hence, the 'closest' designation. This seems like it should be so simple. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine saw that my 'datepicker' class and 'datebtn' class have the same parent. So I have to use 'closest' to navigate up then 'find' to navigate back down. Like this:

```
$(this).closest('.form-group').find('.datepicker').focus();
```

This worked.